# Pass variable from template (phtml) to CMS page

Tags: magento2, phtml, static-block

I have this code, which is rendering a static block in a template file (phtml).

```
$_html = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
        ->setBlockId('test-block')
        ->toHtml();
```

Is it possible to pass a variable into the static block?

Example.

```
$_html = $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
    ->setData('test','test 123')
    ->setBlockId('test-block')
    ->toHtml();
```

And then in the static block display it like this `{{var test}}`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
$_html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Vender\Module\Block\test")->setData('test','test 123')->setTemplate("Vender_Module::test.phtml")->toHtml();
```

you can display data using this way

> $this->getData('test');

Comment: I want to access this variable in the static block. I can't use PHP there.